Firebird Hibernate Dialect generates CONCAT, which is not valid syntax
Specification: Firebird 2.5, Hibernate 6.2 or 6.5 - yes I know this is odd composition since Firebird 2.5 is pretty outdated but for a while I have to live with it.
When I call custom method in CrudRepository or PagingAndSortingRepository with LIKE parameter the generated statement includes CONCAT function which is not supported by Firebird 2.5.
Example:
-- Controller
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(1, 10);
Page<MaterialBrand> items = repository.findByNormQuery(query, paging);

-- Repository
@Query(
      value = "select distinct t_m_gatunki.gatunek, .... where norm_symbol like %:norm%",
      nativeQuery = true
 )
 Page<MaterialBrand> findByNormQuery(@Param("norm") String norm, Pageable pageable);

Generated statement looks like this:
select distinct t_m_gatunki.gatunek ... where norm_symbol like CONCAT('%',?,'%')
Which results in Error.
When I use Database Tool to test query it is OK when query looks like this:
select distinct t_m_gatunki.gatunek ... where norm_symbol like '%' || 'norm_symbol' || '%')
So the question is - how to make workaround of this issue?
I have been browsing through Hibernate source code - especially FirebirdDialect (in hope of some custom modifications), but I can not find where exactly CONCAT function is inserted.
Hope for any solution

Your query is wrong, instead of like %:norm%, you need to use like '%' || :norm || '%'. That is, the % needs to be in a string literal, and you need to concatenate this together with ||. I'm surprised that Hibernate or Spring Data JPA even converts it for you, I wouldn't expect that for a native query.

Yes, you are right. I tried some other query modifications but did not invent this simply solution :(. As usuall your assistance is invaluable. Thanks.

Your welcome. I'm surprised that it even worked, so I'm going to dig to see where it's doing this to see if I can change that to use || instead.

I have other project working with MariaDB and the query's syntax is -  like %:param% - and that works. Generated statement has CONCAT('%',?,'%') function but MariaDB reads it. So somwhere this syntax is translated.

Try to use value = "select distinct t_m_gatunki.gatunek, .... where norm_symbol containing :norm" instead. CONTAINING predicate doesn't need additional symbols in the pattern so Hibernate has no reason to generate CONCAT call.

@user13964273 Confirmed. This solution works as well. Thanks

It is not Hibernate doing this transformation, so I guess it is in Spring Data JPA.
